# shiny "ERROR: Tabs should all be unnamed arguments"

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a UI in shiny for an easy to use analysis package I am creating in R. I haven't worked on it in several months but recently got back in. I am building the app to run exclusively on users local machines using runApp().

Unfortunately, when I launched the app after updating all my libraries I get the following error:

```
Error : Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: types
```

Along with this in the console:

```
Warning: Error in build: Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: types Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: build
    55: buildTabset
    54: tabsetPanel
    53: tag
    52: tags$div
    51: div
    50: mainPanel
    49: sidebarLayout
    48: tag
    47: tags$div
    46: div
    45: tabPanel
    44: structure
    43: navbarMenu
    42: navbarPage
    41: shinyUI
     1: runApp Error : Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: types
```

I went back to shiny version 0.13.2 and it works no problem. I have not been able to track down the changes between versions that is causing this. The package I am working on can be found [here](https://github.com/p-schaefer/BenthicAnalysis).

EDIT: Forgot to mention I am currently using shiny version 0.14

Comment: we can't help you if you don't show us the exact code that produces the error. Pointing to a full package on github with hundreds/thousands of lines of code is not very helpful unfortunately because people don't have the time to go through that. Try to produce a small example that shows the problem

Comment: Never mind, I found the culprit. The tabsetPanel() function must have previously accepted a "types" argument (or my typo never caused a problem before). I changed that argument to "type" and it works again. Sorry for not posting the exact code that was causing the problem, but in this situation I hadn't changed anything so I didn't know where to even begin troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the similar problem.

But this problem is not typo for me, it seems that the error is because of the 'parameter' which is not used.

My problem is `Error : Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: status`

So I delete all the status parameter in my code, then it works well.

Just for reference.

Comment: I have this issue as well. But I don't want to delete my status parameter as it gives the color to my boxes and tabboxes:
``tabBox(id = "tabbox_trans",width=12, status='info',br()``
Did you find a workaround for keeping the colors?

Comment: to come back on my own question. Apparently only for tabBoxes ``status='info'`` triggers errors.

Comment: I haven't find the solution.
In my situation, this error only occurs on windows, not on mac.
I have no idea.

Comment: This smells like a bug. I have the same problem. Code is ok in linux, but error in windows.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when using shiny 0.14 together with shinydashboard 0.5.1.

Solution: update shinydashboard to 0.5.3 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my version of Shiny (to 1.0.3, although it may have happened in an earlier version too).  This error message appeared:

```
Error : Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: title
```

This was due to the presence of a `tabsetPanel` parameter called "title". Once I deleted this parameter, the problem disappeared.

BTW: I replaced it with the following snippet *before* the `tabsetPanel`:

```
br(),
h3("Hello"),
br(),
```

to achieve the same `title` effect